# Javafx Textfield - getText() empty?

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I have a TextField in javafx created in the FXML. It links up to a variable named "thesholdBox" (as seen below, instantiation not show). I have the field listening for KeyEvents, but whenever I enter values in the field, "getText()" always returns an empty string.

Java code:

```
@FXML
public void threshBox(KeyEvent e) {
    //always empty unless I set it manually using "thresholdBox.setText("TESTING")" or something
    String newValue = thresholdBox.getText();
    System.out.println("Text: " + newValue);
}
```

FXML:

```
<TextField fx:id="thresholdBox" layoutX="255.0" layoutY="5.0" onKeyTyped="#threshBox" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="91.0" promptText="0.00" />
```

Screenshot Example:

[image]

Now, normally I would expect thresholdBox.getText() to return "TEST." Testing shows that the code is definitely being triggered, but each pass always gives me an empty string. Does anyone know why this is? I'm fairly new to Javafx, and while I didn't see anything in documentation as to why this problem is happening, it's entirely possible I missed something.

Let me know if I can make my question any clearer.

Thank you!

UPDATE: Relevant code -

```
//here are the only two other places thresholdBox is used. 
//I cropped irrelevant variable declarations, since they do not interact with thresholdBox. 

//class variable
@FXML
TextField thresholdBox;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    thresholdBox = new TextField();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of the controller? I.e. everything that refers to `thresholdBox` (declaration, any references in other methods, etc)?

Comment: Sure thing, one moment. Ok, question has been edited.

Comment: Don't use `thresholdBox = new TextField()`... You assign a new text field to `thresholdBox` (replacing the one defined in the FXML file). So when you call `getText()` you are getting the text of the new text field (which isn't even displayed), instead of the one you created in the FXML.

Comment: Excellent! It looks like that did it. I'm getting values now. Thank you :)

Comment: Bottom line is that you should **never** assign values to a variable annotated with `@FMXL`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll remove all other similar initializations in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I shouldn't have been using "thresholdBox = new TextField();" in my initialize function, as that was overriding my fxml TextField.

Thank you, James_D, for your answer.